# Some general questions on Generative Adversarial Networks

Tags: gan

**Generative Adversarial Networks** are a new type of Adversarial Networks, introducing by "Goodfellow" in 2014. Usually implemented via DeepNNs and they are very powerful in generating "Realistic" outputs which can not be distinguished from a "Real" data.
[image: GAN Diagram]
They are created from two main parts. a Generative and a Discriminator. The Generative part is trying to create some sample and fool the discriminator to classify it as a "Real" sample. Mathematically they can be represented like this:

### min max V (D, G) = E x∼p data (x) [log D(x)] + E z∼p z (z) [log(1 − D(G(z)))]

There are tons of papers on GANs from noise reduction to image generation.
I have some basic questions about them and I think the answer to these questions can be useful for others too.

1. There are some papers using GANs for extracting better images from a sample. for example "Kevin Schawinski et al 2017 - Generative Adversarial Networks recover features in astrophysical images of galaxies beyond the deconvolution limit" 
   [image: Kevin Schawinski et al 2017]
   as you see they used a GAN to "make" new data based on the sample. but the problem space is very 'Chaotic' (astronomical images and deep space stuff). So isn't a risk here of losing actual data while recreating the sample and fill it with some 'Sampled Patterns' stored in the GAN DeepNN?

---

What is the role of Noise here? in the G part we input some noise(as i understood with the same dimension of the output) to DNN. it uses this noise to create an output to be judged by the D part.

2. I'm not sure but why so many papers decided to use a linear distribution sampling for sampling from the noise. is there any particular reason for that? and is there a study to specifically compared the results of the G part outputs with different noise sampling strategies?
3. what if instead of pure noise we input something else to the G part? what would happen then?

---

In a paper (Han Zhang et al - 2016) they used a two staged GAN. The 1s stage is to produce a 128*128 image from a sentence and noise and in the second stage the output of stage 1 is used to produce a 256*256 more realistic image. it really looks like a 'layered' network. right? so:

4. is it practical to use a deeper GAN with multiple stages? of course it's possible but is it practical? what can be the downsides of it?

---

sorry for so many questions in a single thread.
To Editors: please feel free to edit my poor English and help others to understand the questions better.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

after nothing came from anyone, I like to summarize my own research on the topic.

**Question number 1: Is it ok to use a Generated sample for extracting data from an actual sample?**
There will be some "changed" values in the generated sample but a practical view can help us understand why we might use it. in many applications, the "changed values" are not important as much as they can change the output of a process so it's ok to use a generated sample for these kinds of applications.

**Questions Number 2 and 3: What is the role of noise and noise sampling?**
Noise can role like a balancer! we can for sure change the way we sample from it or even create it(not a pure noise but something else!) but it will lead to a biased Generator to the "noise input". So it might be a good idea to keep it as random as possible.

**Question Number 4: Can we have a Deeper GAN?**
Well, again Practicality is what we must focus on. it is possible to make a "Deeper GAN" but it's only when we need extra processes to be done on a data. in fact, when we input a generated sample from a GAN to another one, we are basically feeding it in instead of the "Noise" so that the G part can do "Something" on it. How many stages do we need? it depends on our design. What are the downsides? for sure it would take a lot to train! but also it can increase some "weird representations" in the final output. cause we are using some Generated Sample as Noise. it might perform well on **Some** cases but there is no guaranty for others.

so. this was my interpretation from what I read and also what I spoke with my professors. please feel free to correct me in comments or post a new Answer.

thanks

Answer (score 3):

Not a complete answer from my side, but adding my 2 cents to Question 3: What happens if you change Noise to another type of distribution?

Essentially you get a Conditional Generative Adversarial Network (CGAN) (Mirza & Osindero, 2014). CGAN's have been used in many applications including image super-resolution (which seems to be the case of the paper you might have referenced regarding astronomical image data), as well as image-to-image translation (Isola et. al. 2016). Superpixel resolution could be seen as a specific case of Image-to-Image translation; other applications include dense semantic labeling and image colorization.